# How to expand an input area height for the Editor cotnrol

Tags: c#, maui

When the number of lines reaches some limit, Editor starts scrolling its text, even if the Editor's HorisontalOptions is set to FillEndExpand.

I would like to expand input area along the entire Editor height.

My MainPage.xaml has this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.MainPage">
    <Grid>

        <Editor HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>

    </Grid>


</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Okay, you need to specify the `WidthRequest` and `HeightRequest` this is because you've done `FillAndExpand` this removes all the `Width` and `Height` values making any element `0,0`. To answer the question you will need to detect the amount of characters that requires to fill the space and use a `Height` property and change it and update the screen. I dont think there is actually any methods that come with it straight out of the box.

Comment: Please give this a try. [Auto-Sizing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/editor#:~:text=and%20Placeholder%20properties.-,Auto%2Dsize%20an%20Editor,-An%20Editor%20can). *When auto-resizing is enabled, the height of the Editor will increase when the user fills it with text, and the height will decrease as the user deletes text.*

Comment: Adding only AutoSize="True" (without HeightRequest, Fill...) helped me. Thank you, 
@ThisQRequiresASpecialist